# Python - Using threads or a queue to iterate over a for loop that calls a function

Tags: python, multithreading, for-loop, queue, python-2.6

I'm fairly new to python and am making a script that allows one to bring point cloud data from other programs into Autodesk Maya. I have my script functioning fine but what i'm trying to do is make it faster. I have a for loop that iterates through a list of numbered files. I.e. datafile001.txt, datafile002.txt and so on. Is what i'm wondering is if there is a way to have it to do more then one at a time, possibly using threads or a queue? Below I have the code i have been working on:

```
     def threadedFuntion(args):
         if len(sourceFiles) > 3:
             for count, item in enumerate(sourceFiles):
                     t1=Thread(target=convertPcToPdc,args=(sourceFiles[filenumber1], particlesName, startframe, endframe, pdcIncrements, outputDirectory, variableFolder, acceptableArrayforms, dataType))
                     t1.start()
                     t2=Thread(target=convertPcToPdc,args=(sourceFiles[filenumber2], particlesName, startframe, endframe, pdcIncrements, outputDirectory, variableFolder, acceptableArrayforms, dataType))
                     t2.start()
                     t3=Thread(target=convertPcToPdc,args=(sourceFiles[filenumber3], particlesName, startframe, endframe, pdcIncrements, outputDirectory, variableFolder, acceptableArrayforms, dataType))
                     t3.start()
                     t4=Thread(target=convertPcToPdc,args=(sourceFiles[filenumber4], particlesName, startframe, endframe, pdcIncrements, outputDirectory, variableFolder, acceptableArrayforms, dataType))
                     t4.start()
```

This obviously doesn't work for a number of reasons, first it only will create 4 threads, I would like to be able to give an option for more or less. Second it errors because it's trying to reuse a thread? Like I said i'm quite new to python and am a little over my head, I've been reading several posts on here but can't get one to work quite right. I think a queue might be something I need but couldn't quite figure it out, I experimented with the condition statement and with the join statement, but once again couldn't get what I want.

I guess to be more specific what I want to achieve is that the function is reading through a text file, retrieving coords and then exporting them as a binary file for maya to read. It's common for one of these text files to have 5-10 million x,y,z coords which takes quite some time. It takes around 30mins-1hour to do 1 file on a pretty beastly computer, task manager says python is only using 12% processor and around 1% ram, so if I could do multiple of these at once, it would make doing those 100 or more files go by a lot faster. I wouldn't think it would be to hard to multithread/queue up a for loop, but I've been lost and trying failing solutions for about a week.

Thank you all for any help, I really appreciate it and think this website is amazing. This is my first post, but I feel like I have completely learned python just from reading on here.

Comment: if your task is IO-bound (the program spends most of the time waiting for data from disk) then adding threads that compete for a disc access won't help to improve performance. If task is CPU-bound (the program processes the data slower than the disk is able to provide it) then in your case you could use multiprocessing module to process the files in different processes if you have multiple CPUs. @CaptainMurthy's example should work as is if you remove `threading` names and use `from multiprocessing import Process, Lock` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass threading.Thread and put your work function in that class as part of run().

```
import threading
import time
import random

class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, srcfile, printlock,**kwargs):
        super(Worker,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.srcfile = srcfile
        self.lock = printlock # so threads don't step on each other's prints

    def run(self):
        with self.lock:
            print("starting %s on %s" % (self.ident,self.srcfile))
        # do whatever you need to, return when done
        # example, sleep for a random interval up to 10 seconds
        time.sleep(random.random()*10)
        with self.lock:
            print("%s done" % self.ident)


def threadme(srcfiles):
    printlock = threading.Lock()
    threadpool = []
    for file in srcfiles:
        threadpool.append(Worker(file,printlock))

    for thr in threadpool:
        thr.start()

    # this loop will block until all threads are done
    # (however it won't necessarily first join those that are done first)
    for thr in threadpool:
        thr.join()

    print("all threads are done")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    threadme(["abc","def","ghi"])
```

As requested, to limit the number of threads, use the following:

```
def threadme(infiles,threadlimit=None,timeout=0.01):
    assert threadlimit is None or threadlimit > 0, \
           "need at least one thread";
    printlock = threading.Lock()
    srcfiles = list(infiles)
    threadpool = []

    # keep going while work to do or being done
    while srcfiles or threadpool:

        # while there's room, remove source files
        # and add to the pool
        while srcfiles and \
           (threadlimit is None \
            or len(threadpool) < threadlimit):
            file = srcfiles.pop()
            wrkr = Worker(file,printlock)
            wrkr.start()
            threadpool.append(wrkr)

        # remove completed threads from the pool
        for thr in threadpool:
            thr.join(timeout=timeout)
            if not thr.is_alive():
                threadpool.remove(thr)

    print("all threads are done")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for lim in (1,2,3,4):
        print("--- Running with thread limit %i ---" % lim)
        threadme(("abc","def","ghi"),threadlimit=lim)
```

Note that this will actually process the sources in reverse (due to the list pop()). If you require them to be done in order, reverse the list somewhere, or use a deque and popleft().

Comment: threads probably should be daemons and join() have a timeout to be able to kill the processing easily (is_alive() might be necessary in this case)

Comment: @CaptainMurphy I'm working on experimenting with the code above, if i'm thinking correctly this will create a new thread for each srcfile? or is it going to create just one thread and go through all the srcfiles one at a time? If the first is correct and to many srcfiles are selected it would crash the computer, if the second is correct then would it really be any faster then a for loop? How could i specify to use for example 5 threads?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian is_alive() is what I originally tried to do the first time I experimented with threads, but I just couldn't get it to work

Comment: @Burninghelix123: I'm talking about the loop with thr.join(). Without the `timeout` parameter for join() the program responds poorely to `Ctrl + C` (KeyboardInterrupt). is_alive is necessary to find out whether the timeout occurred

Comment: This will make as many threads as there are source files. Unless you have thousands and thousands of files, the computer will be okay. If you must limit the number, then only add a subset of the files to the threadpool. In the join loop, make it a non-blocking join (i.e. use a timeout as suggested), and whenever a worker thread returns and there is another srcfile to be processed, add it to the threadpool (and start() it). Continue until no more srcfiles.

Comment: @CaptainMurphy You sir are awesome, thanks for spending so much time to help me, I do have one more question, though I feel silly for asking it.
Under the run def, if I swap out the sleep with a print, the print doesn't appear to work, is there a reason for this? Also the print function before and after the sleep command also don't appear to show up, the ones saying "starting %s on %s"

Comment: @Burninghelix123 Maybe it's Python version or platform issue? The prints work for me in Python 3.2.3 for windows. A forked process will normally share stdin/stdout with parent process, but depending on the details of process spawning for whatever the threading backend is, it could be getting its own stdout. You could write to a file instead and see what sys.stdout is pointing to, or workaround it by giving the Worker thread a handle back to the main thread in order to print (protect it with a lock though).

Comment: @Burninghelix123 Oh, and if you follow JF Sebastian's suggestion of using multiprocessing instead of threading, you won't see those prints for the reasons I mentioned above.

Comment: @CaptainMurphy You sir are a gentleman and a scholar, I got it all working flawlessly, thanks for the help! P.s. The printing issue was with the interpreter IDLE in my case, when running through command prompt no problems, Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: @Burninghelix123: `print` works just fine with multiprocessing/threading in Python. Here's [an example that uses `multiprocessing`](http://ideone.com/puQlu). Note: without a lock the output might be mixed. For long-running processes you could [use `logging` module as described here](http://docs.python.org/py3k/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [mrjob](http://packages.python.org/mrjob/) for this.

Mr Job is a python implementation of [map reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).

Below is the mr job code to do a multithreaded word count over a lot of text files:

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob

class MRWordCounter(MRJob):
    def get_words(self, key, line):
        for word in line.split():
            yield word, 1

    def sum_words(self, word, occurrences):
        yield word, sum(occurrences)

    def steps(self):
        return [self.mr(self.get_words, self.sum_words),]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRWordCounter.run()
```

This code maps all the files in parallel (counts the words for each file), then reduces the various counts into one single total word count.

Comment: Hmm interesting i'll have to do some digging into it, thanks for the quick response, I am trying to stay away from any external/ add-on packages (Don't quite know the technical name) but if i need to i will. Just to clarify to, I already have the function that reads files created, just needing to run that function multiple times simultaneously

Comment: In that specific case, this external library is fairly easy to setup and it helps you not reinvent the wheel of multithreaded computation. You can focus on designing how to process the data rather than how to get the data at the right place. Map Reduce is a widely used concept in the industry and you will always find other cases where you can apply it.