# i have issue with threads in python in my project

Tags: python

When I try to prepare my data set then I am getting a error message that `group argument must be None for now`. Please help me out how to solve it.

I am doing it on jupyter, and thread class has some problems.
It showed me this assert group is None:

```
AssertionError: group argument must be None for now
```

and `DataPreparation.ipynb` is another file which has the Prepare class in it.

`DataPreparation.Prepare(Xdata,Ydata,XdataT,YdataT)`

import threading

```
class Prepare(threading.Thread):
    def _init_(self, X, Y, XT, YT, accLabel=None):

        threading.Thread._init_(self)
        self.X=X
        self.Y=Y
        self.XT=XT
        self.YT=YT
        self.accLabel= accLabel
```

With this code, I am getting this error

```
AssertionError: group argument must be None for now
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you share the code. Also, I think this post can help you, check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349997/assertionerror-when-threading-in-python according to that, you maybe just need to pass parameters using keywords.

Comment: @Ferd i added the code to post ..now can you plz help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Code**

In your 'DataPreparation' file(I used a .py file for this, I'm not familiar with using IPython notebook files as modules):

```
import threading

class Prepare(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, x, y, xt, yt, acclabel=None):
        super().__init__() # Python 3.x

        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.xt=xt
        self.yt=yt
        self.acclabel= acclabel
```

And then, in your work/test .ipynb file:

```
import DataPreparation 

xdata=1
ydata=2
xdatat=3
ydatat=4

# Use keyword references
DataPreparation.Prepare(x=xdata, y=ydata,
                        xt=xdatat, yt=ydatat)
```

**Result**

'Prepare' instance created.
[image]

I also recomend you to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067421/threading-and-passing-values-with-kwargs-errors-to-typeerror), could be helpful for future interaction with Thread class arguments.